# ODataController and Streaming example

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have the following requirement. I have a odata contract as follows:

```
public class videoStreamResponse
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Action<Stream> VideoData { get; set; }
}

List<videoStreamResponse> exportVideo(string[] ids);
```

My odata service is exposing a list of videoStreamResponse . There will be odata action that returns the list of video stream response.

In the service implementation we call into another service that streams the data. We want to return this to the caller without having to deserialize into memory. Instead I need to stream the contents from the backend video service to the caller directly where by I need to write to the VideoData which is a delegate that returns a stream.

The middle tier service should not deserialize and serialize since that would increase the memory.

Is there any standard patterns or approach to do this with dotnet core and asp.net mvc odata framework.

Thanks

Comment: If possible, could you please provide detailed information about what you had tried on your side? It could give a better idea regarding the said issue.

Comment: Few things that I tried was to return a delegate like Action<stream> and bind a function to this and so that when the data is dereferenced the Action would be called and we can send the data to the caller. But that did not work.

Comment: The Backend service that we call into is return PipeReader. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipelines.pipereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0 Tried with calling AsStream on the pipereader to read the data in delayed manner.